# Mixpanel how to check if user exist?

Tags: mixpanel

I am currently working with mixpanel api. In this I want to set a profile for the people who has registered on the page. So is there a function through which we can check whether a particluar user exists in profile.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to use People analytics and have a user profile within  MP where you can see all properties and events for this particular user, right?

If you identify a user through Mixpanel (ex. through his userId from Db) and track an event, it will automatically appear in Mixpanel and you have kind of Profile in People Analytics where you can see all about the particular user.

Does that answer help you? If I got your question wrong, please clarify.